# Python tips for working with an unstable `API`

Tags: python, api, concurrency, python-requests

My app is using a third-party `API`. It polls that `API` regularly at several endpoints. In also makes some additional calls to the `API` based on user's interaction with the app. The `API` is very slow, most requests take well over a second. The `API` is very flaky - timeouts are common, `500` errors are common, session key often randomly expires (even when defined "keep_alive" endpoint is called regularly). There is no option to use another `API`.

What would be the best practices for dealing with such an `API`?

How to disable concurrent requests to this `API` on the `requests` level. So if one request is waiting for a response - the second request is not initiated? This should be done on "per-domain" basis, other requests to other domains should still be done concurrently.

Any other settings to toggle with `requests` to make it easier to deal with such an `API`?

Comment: Why do you have to use such a crappy API?

Comment: "What would be the best practices for dealing with such an API?" > Replace the provider presuming they could not be talked some sense into.

Comment: Well, if I could find a better one which would achieve the same goals - I would. This particular project is my pet project, so I don't HAVE to. But at work, I also occasionally come across poorly designed or unstable APIs. Not every API was built in the past 5 years. I think this is quite common problem TBH.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions to "replace API". As I said in the question `There is no option to use another API.`. I've spent weeks looking for an alternative. At some point you just have to face the reality, if you want to have this functionality then this is what you have to use..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your main problem is to serialize calls to that API in a multi-threaded (or multi process) application, a simple way would be to wrap it into a new module and consistenly use locking in that module.

If different clients can use a web API concurrently and you need to serialize the requests for performance reasons, you could imagine a dedicated serializing proxy. Just use above method in the proxy.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. I don't know why haven't I thought about it myself. Proxy is definitely the best solution for me. Yes, other clients might use the same API, and wrapping up `requests` is bound to end up in a mess (for me at least). But having a local proxy, which will have all the logic for the `API`'s quirks looks like a splendid idea and a great way to separate concerns.

Answer (score 5):

**What would be the best practices for dealing with such an API?**

In SRE we pretty much always assume that API's can never be trusted,  Because of this there are a number of patterns that may help:

- [Circuit Breaking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/circuit-breaker)
- Caching
- Timeouts
- Retry/Backoff

References:

- https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Circuit-Breaker
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/category/resiliency
- http://resilience4j.github.io/resilience4j/
- https://www.envoyproxy.io/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Things that you mention are quite advance - I haven't worked with things like "L7 proxy" before. Perhaps if my application will make it out of the MVP phase and a switch to C# or Java will be on the horizon - we would use the libraries that you've mentioned.

Comment: Sorry I should have specified that I put those as references because IMO their documentation is awesome.